# Learning automation with Python, and am having an issue with with this bit of code. Perhaps another set of eyes?

Tags: python

I am sure it is something simple, but no matter how I define (number), it still kicks out an error as (number) is not defined. Thank you in advance.

```
def multiplication_table(number):
    multiplier = 1
    while multiplier <= 5:
        result = 1
    if False:
        break
    return result
print((number) + "x" + (multiplier) + "=" + (result))
x += 1

multiplication_table(3) 
# Should print: 3x1=3 3x2=6 3x3=9 3x4=12 3x5=15

multiplication_table(5) 
# Should print: 5x1=5 5x2=10 5x3=15 5x4=20 5x5=25

multiplication_table(8) 
# Should print: 8x1=8 8x2=16 8x3=24
```

Comment: Did you mess up your indentation? The `print` and `x += 1` are outside the function, that seems unintended

Answer (score 1):

I see the following mistakes in your code:
(1) The if statement does nothing as it is never accessed due to the statement always being false.
(2) the print statement should be in the while loop
(3) multiplier should be incremented by one each while iteration
(4) return statement can be removed as you are not using it, you are only printing
(5) you should convert the ints to str in the print statement
(6) result should be set to multiplier*number

The following code should work:

```
def multiplication_table(number):
    multiplier = 1
    while multiplier <= 5:
        result = multiplier * number
        print(str(number) + "x" + str(multiplier) + "=" + str(result))
        multiplier += 1
```

Comment: btw: `print(f'{number}x{multiplier}={result}')` is much shorter (Python3.6+), also better to use a `for` loop: `for multiplier in range(1, 6):`, then you don't need to keep track of it

Comment: Thank you for your response, I appreciate it.